# How do I update my location data in Firebase infrequently?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, location

I am using Significant-Change Location service which updates location every 500 meters or more. So, if a user goes on a long drive, the location is updated very frequently and since I am updating my firebase database with the location with every update, that will be a lot of writes. How can I limit the times I update my database for example, update the db every hour or update only when new location updates have stopped or something else?

```
This is my current code:


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,  didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
         let lastLocation = locations.last!
               lat = lastLocation.coordinate.latitude
               long = lastLocation.coordinate.longitude
               db.collection(coll).document(uid).updateData(["loc": GeoPoint(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)])
 
    }
```

Comment: How about writing a timer, when the timer fire, get the current location and compare with previous one. It it's difference, then update it.

Comment: You can't use a timer,  but you could look at the time stamp associated with the `CLLocation` and only update Firebase if there has been some time since the previous update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was say if it has been >= x  miles since the last update in the db, then update again, else do nothing